# what is the current operator of an interacting electron gas?

Tags: condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, electric-current, conductors

If i have an electron gas with coulomb interactions, what would be the current, operator. I would write the Heisenberg equation of motion for the density operator, than write the continuity equation for density operator, then solve it.